# Kubuntu Mouse does not work while installing

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, mouse

I try to install Kubuntu from USB to my harddrive. After the start, the Cursor moves, but it does nothing on right and left click.
I´ve tried do install Kubuntu via EFI and without. Both time i get the same results.
I also tried a normal USB mouse.

Kubuntu inside Virtualbox works fine for me.

My Mainboard is an MSI B85-G41 PC Mate.

Kind regards
Handas

Comment: Do you have a discrete graphics card?

Comment: I have an AMD R9 fury x

Comment: You may try the new proprietary driver from AMD: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx . This suggestion is based on your report that the symptom occurs also with a regular known good USB mouse (and other unnamed pointing device) and that it may be related with graphics drivers.

Comment: i installed the driver correct. But this still does not work;

Comment: If i open a console (Which has the focus) and left-click the desktop. The console loses it´s focus. So Kubuntu get´s the Signal from the mouse, but does not interpret the command correct, i think;

Comment: After i logout and login again, my mouse works fine. But my keyboard does not